# Given an Ethereum address is it possible to get it's solana equivalent?

Tags: solana-program, address

If I have an Ethereum address can I convert it to a Solana equivalent such that the same private key for the Ethereum_address_a could also be used for Solana_address_a?

Comment: https://chainstack.com/how-do-ethereum-and-solana-generate-public-and-private-keys/ ?

Answer (score 1):

In both systems, the private key is 256 bits / 32 bytes, so you could use the same 32 bytes as the private key for both Solana and Ethereum. This is likely how cross-chain wallets operate.

Note that the public keys will be different because of the different cryptographic curves used by each chain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! As long as you have access to the private key. This is exactly how multi-chain wallets handle it.

With the same private key (and by association, seed phrase), the wallet can use the desired blockchains standard key derivation functions to derive a valid blockchain address on that chain.

In the end, a wallet's secret key is just an array of bytes. These bytes can be reused in anyway you want, including for interesting things with the native web api crypto functions for data encryption :)

The public keys (aka wallet address) on Solana and Ethereum are very different though. So you should expect to get different outputs of course

If you want to dig into it a bit, you could look at the [Backpack wallet](https://github.com/coral-xyz/backpack) code which should have some stuff in it (note the license though)